# Django - Foreign Key not working

Tags: python, sql, django, django-templates

I'm trying to display some data on a webpage using a foreach loop and django.
I do not seem to understand how to use a lookup table that I have created in my Database.

These are the columns from the DB:

```
budget_audit_table:
-BudgetID
-BudgetTypeID <- Foreign Key
-ObjectAuditID
-CustomerID
-DateOfTransaction
-BudgetObject
-Amount

budget_type:
-BudgetTypeID
-BudgetType
```

As you can probably assume in the model.py, the BudgetTypeID is a foreign key.
In the budget_type table I currently have 2 rows:
- Expense: ID 1
- Income: ID 2

Now the problem I'm having is I have searched for a few days now trying to understand Django's API more and I'm struggling to understand how do I for each row that is displayed from the budget_audit_table, how do I instead of displaying the BudgetTypeID (eg 1), it displays the BudgetType (eg Expense)?

Here is my view & template

view.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from models import BudgetAuditTable
from models import BudgetType

@login_required
def index(request):
    budgetauditlist = BudgetAuditTable.objects.order_by('-budgetid')
    template = loader.get_template('budget/budget.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'budgetauditlist': budgetauditlist,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Template

```
{% for budgetauditobject in budgetauditlist %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgetid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.objectauditid }}{{ budgetauditobject.customerid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.amount }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class BudgetAuditTable(models.Model):
    budgetid = models.IntegerField(db_column='BudgetID', primary_key=True)
    budgettypeid = models.ForeignKey('BudgetType', db_column='BudgetTypeID', blank=True, null=True)
    objectauditid = models.IntegerField(db_column='ObjectAuditID', blank=True, null=True)
    customerid = models.IntegerField(db_column='CustomerID', blank=True, null=True)
    dateoftransaction = models.DateField(db_column='DateOfTransaction', blank=True, null=True)
    budgetobject = models.CharField(db_column='BudgetObject', max_length=255, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(db_column='Amount', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'budget_audit_table'

class BudgetType(models.Model):
    budgettypeid = models.IntegerField(db_column='BudgetTypeID', primary_key=True)
    budgettype = models.CharField(db_column='BudgetType', max_length=25, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'budget_type'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your template try:

```
{% for budgetauditobject in budgetauditlist %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgetid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid.budgettype }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.objectauditid }}{{ budgetauditobject.customerid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.amount }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Furthermore you should rename your `BudgetType` ForeignKey field in your model simply to `BudgetType` since your ForeignKey relation represents another entity.

See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) for the relationship lookups.

Answer (score 1):

`budgetauditobject.budgettypeid` specify a BudgetType object, you should use the attributes under BudgetType like this:

```
{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid.budgettype }}
{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid.budgettypeid }}
```

So, you need to modify the template like this:

```
{% for budgetauditobject in budgetauditlist %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgetid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.objectauditid }}{{ budgetauditobject.customerid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.amount }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Unfortunately when I try this the result returns blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid.budgettype }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, just [follow the relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), like this:

```
{% for budgetauditobject in budgetauditlist %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgetid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid.budgettype }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.objectauditid }}{{ budgetauditobject.customerid }}</td>
    <td>{{ budgetauditobject.amount }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The `.` syntax will allow you to follow and query items from the linked table. `budgetauditobject.bugettypeid.budgettype` means *"get the bugettype field's value of the bugettypid that corresponds to this budgetauditobject"*

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing

```
{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid }}
```

to

```
{{ budgetauditobject.budgettypeid.budgettype }}
```